# Using other models in Django Manager causes ImportError: partially initialized module (due to circular dependency)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following function in my `UserManager` that I use with my `CustomUser` model in my django app.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    ...
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

I needed to create a corresponding `UserProfile` object when a user is registered, so I updated the `_create` function as follows:

```py
from profiles.models import UserProfile
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        # Create the user profile
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

But this throws:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'CustomUser' from partially initialized module 'user
> s.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (../users/models.py)

My `CustomUser` is defined as follows:

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    auth_provider = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        default=AUTH_PROVIDERS.get('email'))
    objects = UserManager()
```

And the `UserProfile` model is defined as follows:

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, 
        null=True, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="profile")
    ...
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Why would using `UserProfile` **in the Manager** cause circular import error? I understand if I used `UserProfile` in the `CustomUser` model itself, but isn't a manager just an interface for db queries?

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey),

> This sort of reference, called a ***lazy relationship***, ***can be useful when resolving circular import dependencies between two applications***.

So, you can use ***`app_name.ModelName`*** syntax to connect the **`CustomUser`** to **`UserProfile`** as

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        "my_app.CustomUser" # Change is here, 
        null=True, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="profile")
    ...
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this caused my UserProfile form to throw: `Cannot create form field for 'user' yet, because its related model '<my_app>.CustomUser' has not been loaded yet `